# Unable to create a replica set in mongoDB: "ok" : 0

Tags: mongodb, virtualbox, centos7, replicaset

I'm using Oracle Virtualbox to host 3 VM running CentOS 7.

Vbox network setup is:

**primary-db**      Adapter1: NAT Mode, no forwarding rules in network settings & Adapter2: Bridge Mode, promiscuous mode=Allow all

**secondary-db1**   Adapter1: NAT Mode, no forwarding rules in network settings & Adapter2: Bridge Mode, promiscuous mode=Allow all

**secondary-db2**   Adapter1: NAT Mode, no forwarding rules in network settings & Adapter2: Bridge Mode, promiscuous mode=Allow all

1. I've added the 27017 port to the firewall. (I've also added 27018 to
   test)
2. Created /data/db.
3. I've added all the host IPs on each servers' /etc/hosts file and
   commented the 127.0.0.1 line
4. I've configured all the mongo.conf files like this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid 
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 192.168.1--.---,127.0.0.1

replication:
  replSetName: "replica01"
```

**Problem:**

Now when I run the

```
# mongo -host <secondary-db server/192.168.---.---> -port 27017
```

In the primary server, I can enter the mongo shell of the secondaries

But when I try to use the

```
rs.add('secondary-db1')
```

or

```
rs.add('secondary-db1:27017')
```

I keep getting this:

```
replica01:PRIMARY> rs.add('secondary-db')
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1581381570, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1581381570, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
replica01:PRIMARY>
```

I even tried to comment the bindIP line to test but it gives me the same result. have I over looked something? 
Ive used this [tutorial as my reference.](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/mongodb-replication-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 0):

just to sanity check:

> each node has a separate/differing port
>   each node has a separate/differing dir folder

it's not clear from your post...you state only 1 port via the firewall but each node needs its own port, folder - - they're all separate and in parallel....

log directly onto 1 node and first do:
rs.initiate()

then perform the rs.add for the other 2 nodes

this will group them into a replica set

Comment: do you mean if i opened 27017 on node 1, i should open 27018 on node 2 and 27019 on node 3?

Answer (score 0):

if your question is the set up of the nodes - definitely yes - they each must be a separate and different port, and they need to reside in separate dir folders....

if your question is about firewall/front end: I work more on the data side with queries rather than the front end...but it is a replica set and if the primary goes down your app needs to work to any of the secondary(s) (whichever gets elected Primary is random)….

Mongo has a free university and course M103 is specifically about spinning up replica sets - you can watch the videos pretty quickly to get up to speed....